# Clipper.js not working with set of coordinates

Tags: javascript

I am trying to adapt the 'simplify polygon' function from the the clipper.js library. I am not sure I understand what is wrong with the following script:

```
   var five_pointed_star = [{
  "X": 114.11152626295,
  "Y": 22.213863709855
}, {
  "X": 114.11262775355,
  "Y": 22.214272283475
}, {
  "X": 114.1133008867,
  "Y": 22.214885143905
}, {
  "X": 114.1133008867,
  "Y": 22.21619257949
}, {
  "X": 114.11164865079,
  "Y": 22.216233436852
}, {
  "X": 114.11152626295,
  "Y": 22.213863709855
}];

var ten_pointed_star = ClipperLib.Clipper.SimplifyPolygon(five_pointed_star, ClipperLib.PolyFillType.pftNonZero);
console.log(ten_pointed_star);
```

The code however works as expected if I change the five_pointed_star to the following:

```
var five_pointed_star = [{
  "X": 147,
  "Y": 313
}, {
  "X": 247,
  "Y": 34
}, {
  "X": 338,
  "Y": 312
}, {
  "X": 86,
  "Y": 123
}, {
  "X": 404,
  "Y": 124
}];
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polygon uses a path as a parameter, and the path has the following definition in the documentation:

> This structure contains a sequence of IntPoint vertices defining a single contour (see also terminology). Paths may be open and represent a series of line segments bounded by 2 or more vertices, or they may be closed and represent polygons. Whether or not a path is open depends on context. Closed paths may be 'outer' contours or 'hole' contours. Which they are depends on orientation.

And IntPoint reads:

> The IntPoint structure is used to represent all vertices in the Clipper Library.

So this means that the numbers you need to give it, have to be Integers - whereas you were trying to use floating point numbers, or floats for short.
So if you use Integers it should always work fine, if your calculations return floats, you can use rounding methods like [floor()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor/) to get rid of the values after the dot.

Comment: Thank you so much Gunnar. This was driving me a little barmy. Clearly I had not thought it through properly, but then I am puzzled as to why these need to be integers.